# Enable Shortcode for Custom Wordress Widgets

Tags: plugins

I would like to use a shortcode for a Wordpress Widget. I've tried inserting `add_shortcode('test_widget', 'test_load_widget');` at the bottom, but when I tried to load it by calling `[test_widget]` in a post, it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm new to shortcodes and plugins. Kindly please assist.

```
<?php

// Creating the widget 

class test_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
// Base ID of your widget
                'test_widget',
// Widget name will appear in UI
                __('Test Widget', 'test_widget_domain'),
// Widget description
                array('description' => __('Test Widget', 'test_widget_domain'),)
        );
    }

// Creating widget front-end
// This is where the action happens
    public function widget($args, $instance) {
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
// before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if (!empty($title))
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

// This is where you run the code and display the output
        echo __('Hello, World!', 'test_widget_domain');
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

// Widget Backend 
    public function form($instance) {
        if (isset($instance['title'])) {
            $title = $instance['title'];
        } else {
            $title = __('New title', 'wpb_widget_domain');
        }
// Widget admin form
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:'); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php
    }

// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = (!empty($new_instance['title']) ) ? strip_tags($new_instance['title']) : '';
        return $instance;
    }

}

// Register and load the widget
function test_load_widget() {
    register_widget('test_widget');
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'test_load_widget');
add_shortcode('test_widget', 'test_load_widget');
```

Comment: Your shortcode callback is just registering your widget. You should have another function which instantiate and call the widget() method of your Test Widget

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you please show an example or a doc on how it is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shortcode function will register widget, will not display on a page as a shortcode.

To show widget on a page/post you need to use `the_widget( 'test_widget', $instance, $args );` function.

Codex documentation is [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget)

For example, in your code

```
// Display the widget
function test_show_widget() {
    the_widget( 'test_widget' );
}

add_shortcode('test_widget', 'test_show_widget');
```

Comment: Thanks WisdmLads for your answer. I know about "the_widget" function, but how do I convert it into a shortcode?

Comment: Answer updated with example, please check.